How Custody Settlement Blockchain-Based Solutions Work with Centralized Exchanges
I read How does clearing & settlement work on crypto exchanges and have a follow-up question: Can you explain in more detail how our own custody for settlement on the blockchain would work if we want to integrate it with a public centralized exchange and a private sale?
